# Having trouble implementing my first Decorator pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, hashmap

I have a simple app that takes a string and returns the number of unique characters in the string. It is expected that a string may be passed several times to the method. The method should cache the results, so that when the method is given a string previously encountered, it will retrieve the stored result.

For learning purposes I need to implement caching using decorator pattern. What I learned from the web:

1. First I create an interface

```java
public interface CharCount {
                Map<String, Long> charCount(String input);
        }
```

2. It's simple implementation - without caching

```
public class CharCountImplement {

    Map<String, Long> charCount(String input) {
        return Arrays.stream(input.split(""))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), HashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
    }
}
```

3. Decorator class

```
public abstract class Decorator implements CharCount {
    private CharCount charCount;

    @Override
    public Map<String, Long> charCount(String input) {
        return charCount.charCount(input);
    }
}
```

4. Now I must create the concrete decorator, but I can't quite figure it out

```
public class CachedDecorator extends Decorator {

    // decorator must contain something else

    public Map<String, Long> charCount(String input) {
        // some decoration code - no problem with it
        return super.charCount(input);
    }

}
```

I don't quite catch the principle of this design pattern, and how to use it in my case.
I have watched/read numerous tutorials for pizza and coffee decorators, did not help.

Comment: When you say "decorator must contain something else"... according to whom?

Comment: The decorator would cache the string whose chars are being counted and its counts, and return that if cached, otherwise cache and return the results.

Comment: @MarkPeters I think I need a way to use my new decorator, something like CacheIfNotExist method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To decorate an object of CharCount with caching you can use something like this:

```
public class CachedDecorator extends Decorator {
    // NOTE: you don't realy need the abstract class Decorator
    //       you could also put the `private CharCount charCount;` into this class and let it implement CharCount instead of extending Decorator
    //       then you need to replace super.charCount(input) by charCount.charCount(input) in the charCount method in this class (the line is marked below)

    private Map<String, Map<String, Long>> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public CachedDecorator(CharCount charCount) {
        this.charCount = charCount;//the base object that you are decorating
    }

    public Map<String, Long> charCount(String input) {
        // --- start of the additional, decorating implementation
        //check whether the input string was already processed and is cached
        Map<String, Long> cached = cache.get(input);
        if (cached != null) {
            //we already know the solution, so just return it without calculating
            return cached;
        }
        
        // --- call the super implementation that was decorated (where the super implementation in Decorator calls the charCount method of the CharCount object, that was added in the constructor of this class
        Map<String, Long> calculated = super.charCount(input); //here you may also use charCount.charCount(input); instead of super.charCount(input); (see the NOTE in the top of this class)
        
        // --- cache the result (again a decoration of the implementation)
        cache.put(input, calculated);
        
        // return the result
        return calculated;
    }
}
```

Using the cached Decorator you can do something like this:

```
CharCount simpleCharCount = new CharCountImplement();
CharCount cachingCharCount = new CachedDecorator(simpleCharCount);

simpleCharCount.charCount("Hello World!");// this will just calculate the result, because it's the simple object without cache
simpleCharCount.charCount("Hello World!");// the result is calculated another time

cachingCharCount.charCount("Hello World!");// this will use the simpleCharCount object to calculate the result map of "Hello World!" once
cachingCharCount.charCount("Hello World!");// this time the result is not calculated but just taken from the cache
```

The advantage of the decorator pattern over just creating another implementation, is that you don't have to re-implement the code in your `CharCountImplement` class, but you can just re-use it. Also it is possible to use the `CacheDecorator` in every place where a `CharCount` is expected. So if you have a method, that needs a `CharCount` object as a parameter and was working with a `CharCountImplement` object, you can simply use the `CacheDecorator` instead, without changing any code in the method that you are calling.

In this scenario you could have also created a class that extends `CharCountImplement` to achieve the same effect. But if you want to create another implementation of the `CharCount` interface and have this new implemenation also use a cache, the decorator pattern can save you a lot of work, since you don't need to create this cache subclass for every implementation of `CharCount`, but you can just use the one decorator for every implementation of `CharCount`.
So if you have 4 implementations of `CharCount` you can use 4 subclasses to achive caching, or just 1 decorator. And this effect grows exponentially if you want to use another decorator, so this pattern can be realy helpfull to reduce the number of classes that you need to create and keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).